# Definite article "the" needed after "both" and before a "known plural noun"?

Tags: definite-article

Is it advisable to use the definite article "the" marked in bold at the end of the following text?  It appears after the word "both" and before a "known plural noun".

The first paragraph serves to provide context.

> I think there are two major reasons why it is often difficult to identify who is right on a controversial topic. First, people are often exposed to only one side of the story depending on their background. Second, if an individual wants to spend the time to carefully study both sides, they will not have an easy time. In the internet age, we are exposed to vast amounts of information, and it can be very overwhelming and time-consuming to identify reliable sources and examine the information they provide.

> In this study, we propose a method that addresses both **the(?)** challenges above.

Answer (score 1):

"Both challenges", "both the challenges", and "both of the challenges" are all common and correct.

"Both challenges" is the best writing style because it is shortest.

Comment: Suppose I really care about **grammatical** correctness. I wonder which one works best in the *above example*.